# How to search for a value anywhere in separate spreadsheet and return an offset value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with multiple spreadsheets that need to find values from a different spreadsheet. The main problem is that the value can be anywhere in the spreadsheet within the range (A1:DD1000). i.e. Value from **Sheet1** is 'Shelly', find 'Shelly' in **Sheet2** and return the value which is offset by +2 rows and +1 column.

I have found a formula which will do what I need, however it is very slow and consumes a lot of the computer's resources. How can I convert this excel formula into VBA? (I am very new to VBA)

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet2'!$A$1:$CZ$400='Sheet1'!C2)*ROW('Sheet2'!$A$1:$CZ$400))+2,(SUMPRODUCT(('Sheet2'!$A$1:$CZ$400='Sheet1'!C2)*COLUMN('Sheet2'!$A$1:$CZ$1)))+1,,,("Sheet2"))),"")
```

Comment: You cant use a formula for this. It is not practical. Tomorrow if your worksheets increase then you will add more names to the formula? Use VBA and use `.Find` Lot of exmamples on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you.  Put this in a standard module (In Excel VBA Editor go to Insert -> Module and then copy paste the provided code into the new module).  Code commented to help explain what it's doing and why.

```
Option Explicit 'Always use Option Explicit to avoid typos

'Declare your function name and its arguments
Public Function CUSTOMLOOKUP(ByVal arg_vFind As Variant, _
                             ByVal arg_rSearch As Range, _
                             ByVal arg_lColOffset As Long, _
                             Optional ByVal arg_lRowOffset As Long = 0, _
                             Optional ByVal arg_bExactMatch As Boolean = True) _
  As Variant

    'Declare variables
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rOutput As Range

    'Use Range.Find method to search the provided arg_rSearch range for the arg_vFind value
    Set rFound = arg_rSearch.Find(arg_vFind, , xlValues, arg_bExactMatch)
    If rFound Is Nothing Then
        'No match found, return #VALUE! error
        CUSTOMLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        'Match found, check if the Column and Row offsets will result in a legal cell
        On Error Resume Next    'Use this to suppress an error if this test results in an illegal cell reference
        Set rOutput = rFound.Offset(arg_lRowOffset, arg_lColOffset)
        On Error GoTo 0         'ALWAYS use this to clear the On Error Resume Next condition immediately after the test
        If rOutput Is Nothing Then
            'Offsets result in illegal cell reference, return #REF! error
            CUSTOMLOOKUP = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Else
            'Legal cell reference, return its value as the function output
            CUSTOMLOOKUP = rOutput.Value
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Now that you have your VBA function, commonly referred to as a UDF (User Defined Function), call it by placing this formula in your cell: `=CUSTOMLOOKUP('Sheet1'!C2,'Sheet2'!$A$1:$DD$1000,1,2)`